# Spring Security all endpoints return status 200 but postman returns nothing as response body

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

I want to make a role based jwt application so i build login and registration system. TI was able to run the app exactly like this before but it is not working right now. Only returns 200 OK without any response body.

I debugged all endpoints but didn't catch anything. This is my sample login-registeration endpoints.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class authController {
    @Autowired private authService Authservice;
    @PostMapping("/login/user")
    public LoginResponseDTO loginUser(@RequestBody LoginDTO body){
        return Authservice.loginUser(body.getEmail(), body.getPassword());
    }
    @PostMapping("/register/user")
    public Users registerUser(@RequestBody RegisterDTO body){
        return Authservice.registerUser(body.getFirstname(),body.getLastname(),body.getEmail(), body.getPassword());
    }
}
```

this is my service file

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class authService {
    @Autowired private UserRepo userRepo;
    @Autowired private RoleRepo roleRepo;
    @Autowired private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired private JwtTokenUtil tokenService;
    @Autowired private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired private UserService userService;

    public Users registerUser(String firstname, String lastname, String email, String password){
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);
        Role userRole = roleRepo.findByAuthority("USER").get();

        Set<Role> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        authorities.add(userRole);
        System.out.println("Email: " + email + "Password: " + password);
        return userRepo.save(new Users(firstname,lastname,email,encodedPassword,authorities));
    }
    public LoginResponseDTO loginUser(String email, String password){
        try{
            UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername(email);
            if (passwordEncoder.matches(password, userDetails.getPassword())){

                String token = tokenService.generateToken(userDetails);
                return new LoginResponseDTO(userDetails, token);
            }
            throw new ValidationException("Email veya şifre hatalı.");
        }catch (AuthenticationException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new LoginResponseDTO(null,"");
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my securityconfig file

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final JWTAuthenticationFilter filter;

    public SecurityConfig(JWTAuthenticationFilter filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authManager(UserDetailsService detailsService){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoProvider.setUserDetailsService(detailsService);
        daoProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return new ProviderManager(daoProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
                .csrf(csrf-> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth->{
                    auth.requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
                    auth.requestMatchers("/corpuser/**").hasRole("USER");
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated();
                });
        http.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.sessionManagement(
                session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: a breakpoint at e.printStackTrace(); in the trycatch of the authservice is not activating?